# $\sqrt[b_1]{a_1}+\sqrt[b_2]{a_2}+\cdots+\sqrt[b_k]{a_k}$ not an integer

Tags: number-theory, integers

Is it true that all numbers of the form $\sqrt[b_1]{a_1}+\sqrt[b_2]{a_2}+\cdots+\sqrt[b_k]{a_k}$ are not integers, where $a_i,b_i$ are positive integers such that none of the $k$ terms is an integer? I think this must be a theorem somewhere, probably a fundamental theorem in number theory, but not sure what it would be called.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want to require $a_i , b_i > 1$.

Comment: @EricTowers I required that none of the $k$ terms is an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we may allow $a_i \in\Bbb{Q}_{>0} \setminus \{1\}$ by multiplying through by the least common denominator of the $a_i$.

Let $t_i = \sqrt[b_i]{a_i}$ and suppose  $\sum t_i \in \Bbb{Q}$.  Do you believe $\Bbb{Q}(t_1, \dots, t_k) = \Bbb{Q}(t_1 + \cdots + t_k)$?  If so, $\Bbb{Q}(t_1, \dots, t_k) = \Bbb{Q}$, and every $t_i \in \Bbb{Q}$.

The fact I've used is 5.2(2) at Albu, T., [*Cogalois Theory: An Outline*](http://ssmr.ro/bulletin/pdf/58-3/articol_1.pdf).